# var_dump showing proper array but json_encode function returns false when trying to encode the same array

Tags: php

I want to encode data retrieved from database into json. Here is my codes..

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "joomla");     

if($con === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM yv084_content";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$all_result = array();

$intro_result = array();

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$count =0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){          
    $all_result[] = $row;       
}    

while($count<$num_rows){        
    $intro_result[] = strip_tags($all_result[$count]['introtext']);
    //echo strip_tags($all_result[$count]['introtext'])."<hr />";
    $count++;
}

echo "<hr />";
var_dump($intro_result);
echo "<hr />";
$encoded_value = json_encode($intro_result);

var_dump($encoded_value);
echo $encoded_value;
```

when I use `var_dump` function, then i got proper result but when i use `json_encode` function to encode that array it is returning false.. Is there any idea how to encode them..

**Note: There is alot of special characters and html entities so I am using `strip_tags` function.**

please review the result what I got in the browser...

[Screenshot of browser's result](https://plus.google.com/106909501137856850143/posts/chEAYssy7UK?pid=6197202235613951586&oid=106909501137856850143)

Comment: can you paste here result of `var_dump($intro_result);` here please?

Comment: yes just give array result so we can found out something for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per above answer, you cannot convert special characters in array with `json_encode`. However you can try following:

```
$d1 = array("asdadlasdladlasdad adadasdsa", "Nuwakot, Sep. 18: dadasda", "Åland Islands", "<b>test</b>");
array_walk($d1, function(&$value) {
    $value = utf8_encode($value);
});
print_r(json_encode($d1));
```